# show sql data from User input

Tags: sql, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

The code below inserts whatever data is typed into the text fields: name1 and phone1 into my database and I need to be able to type in stored data and retrieve it

```
def insert():

   name1 = textin.get()
   phone1 = textinn.get()
   conn = sqlite3.connect('D:\lastfm-dataset-360K\msd.sqlite3')
   with conn:
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('INSERT INTO people(name, phone) VALUES(?,?)',(name1, phone1,))
      db.close()


but=Button(root,padx=2,pady=2,text='Submit',command=insert,font=('none 13 bold'))
but.place(x=60,y=100)
```

I need to retrieve the records by typing them into the same text field and then print them out. So far I have this but Im confused with the SQL.

```
def show():
   name1 = textin.get()
   phone1 = textinn.get()
   conn = sqlite3.connect('D:\lastfm-dataset-360K\msd.sqlite3')
   with conn:
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM people(name, phone) VALUES(?,?)',(name1, phone1,))
for row in cursor.fetchall():
  print(row)


res=Button(root,padx=2,pady=2,text='Show',command=show,font=('none 13 bold'))
res.place(x=160,y=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO students(name, phone) VALUES(?,?)''',[(name1), (phone1)])
```

and:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = ? AND phone = ?", [(name1),(phone1)])
```

---

Newcode:

```
def insert():
   name1 = textin.get()
   phone1 = textinn.get()
   conn = sqlite3.connect('D:\lastfm-dataset-360K\msd.sqlite3')
   with conn:
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO students(name, phone) VALUES(?,?)''',[(name1), (phone1)])
      db.close()


def show():
   name1 = textin.get()
   phone1 = textinn.get()
   conn = sqlite3.connect('D:\lastfm-dataset-360K\msd.sqlite3')
   with conn:
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = ? AND phone = ?", [(name1),(phone1)])
      for row in cursor.fetchall():
          print(row)

res=Button(root,padx=2,pady=2,text='Show',command=show,font=('none 13 bold'))
res.place(x=160,y=100)
```

Comment: `db.close()` .. what is `db`? currently thats an NameError?